# Explicit Base Integer Conversion Mistake

Tags: python, typeerror

I just spent like the last hour making what you see below you. It's kinda the first project where I'm actually using stuff from my head. Everything I saw online about the problem I didn't really understand because I don't really have any idea what's going on. I've kinda skipped over a lot of fundamental stuff but I have a feeling I'm doing the function business wrong. Can someone please explain where my code went wrong?

Code:

```py
import random

uname = input("Whats up! What is your username? ")

print("Hiya " + uname + ". Cool name ;)")

global guess_loop


def game():
    question = None
    invalid_input = False
    question = input("Would you like to play my epic guessing game??? [Y/N]")
    if question != "Y" or "N":
        invalid_input: bool = True
    if question == "N":
        print("Fine then I didnt wanna play it with you anyway!")
    if question == "Y":
        guess_loop()
    if invalid_input == True:
        print("Oops its seems you've input a invalid character. Please answer with a uppercase \"Y\" or \"N\"")
        question = None
        game()

global tries

def guess_loop():
    global guess_loop
    random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    invalid_input2 = True
    guess = int(input("Awesome lets play! Ive picked a number beetween one and ten. Try to guess it!"))
    if guess is not int(1, 11):
        invalid_input2 = True
    if guess > random_number:
        tries += 1
        int(input("Too low! guess higher!" + f" This is your {tries}th try!"))
        guess_loop()
    if guess > random_number:
        tries += 1
        int(input("Too high! guess lower!" + f" This is your {tries}th try!"))
        guess_loop()
    if guess == random_number:
        new_game = input(f"Congratulations {uname} you won! Would you like to play again? [Y/N]")
        if new_game != "Y" or "N":
            invalid_input: bool = True
        if new_game == "N":
            print("Fine then I didnt wanna play it with you anyway!")
        if new_game == "Y":
            guess_loop()
        while invalid_input == True:
            print("Oops its seems you've input a invalid character. Please answer with a uppercase \"Y\" or \"N\"")
            guess_loop()

    while invalid_input2 == True:
        print("Oops its seems you've input a invalid character. Please answer with a number between 1 and 10")
        guess_loop()

game()
```

Output:

```
Whats up! What is your username? R33
Hiya R33. Cool name ;)
Would you like to play my epic guessing game??? [Y/N]Y
Awesome lets play! Ive picked a number beetween one and ten. Try to guess it!1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "88888", line 58, in <module>
    game()
  File "88888", line 18, in game
    guess_loop()
  File "88888", line 32, in guess_loop
    if guess is not int(1, 11):
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Comment: `int(1, 11)` is not a valid use of the `int` function. Do you mean something like `if not 1 <= guess < 11:` ?

Comment: `I've kinda skipped over a lot of fundamental stuff` then I'd recommend not doing that, and going back and learning what you're doing. Typing code without understanding it is called [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). I say this because `int(1, 11)` doesn't make sense; you can't convert a tuple of two integers to just an integer, and I don't know why you'd want to do that anyway.

Comment: @RandomDavis All the online tutorials ive gone over are painfully, painfully slow or skim over a lot of stuff. I just decided to look for a programming challenge instead and try to do it my own way. I think if the only thing I cant debug was that one tiny mistake then my approach has been somewhat successful.

Comment: @r_33 doing is definitely the best way to learn, it's just that a "small mistake" like this indicates that there's a lot of basic, fundamental knowledge you've skipped over which is why I said what I did.

Answer (score 0):

`int()` function does not retrun a list as you intended to use it. You might want to change `if guess is not int(1, 11)` to `if guess not in range(1,11)` which returns an iterator and actually checks if the `guess` is not in this range!

Comment: `range(1,11)` doesn't return an iterator. It returns a range object.

Comment: And that's important, because it doesn't have to iterate over all the values when you do a membership test with `in`.

Comment: this doesnt work. Everything returns back as a invalid_integer.

Comment: ``if guess <= 0 or guess >= 11:`` kinda works but for some reason ``1`` isnt working. I dont have time right now to figure this out im going to bed lol

Answer (score 0):

> I've kinda skipped over a lot of fundamental stuff

There's your problem. You really should slow down and use a good tutorial online to understand the fundamental stuff first.

The error

> int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

is telling you that the `int()` function, when called with two arguments expects the first one to be a *string*, and the second one to be an integer giving the base

You probably meant to check if `guess` is in between 1 and 10, for which you need to do:

```
if 1 <= guess <= 10:
```

or

```
if guess in range(1, 11):
```